# не запускается программа на python из-за ошибки

Tags: python

была программа на python "камень ножницы бумага". решил её проапгрейдить, но теперь она не работает из-за какой-то ошибки. откатил всё назад -  ошибка всё равно осталась. помогите найти её, пожалуйста. отступы могут не отображаться, но они есть. вот код:

```
import random

loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    print("камень\ножницы\бумага - выпишите или скопируйте и вставьте выбранное вами слово ниже")
    playerChoice = input()

    a = ["бумага", "камень", "ножницы"]

    botChoice = random.choice(a)
    print(botChoice)

    if playerChoice == botChoice:
        print("повторите")
    elif playerChoice == "бумага":
        if botChoice == "камень":
            print("победил игрок")
        elif botChoice == "ножницы":
            print("победил компьютер")
    elif playerChoice == "ножницы":
        if botChoice == "камень":
            print("победил компьютер")
        elif botChoice == "бумага":
            print("победил игрок")
    elif playerChoice == "камень":
        if botChoice == "бумага":
            print("победил компьютер")
        elif botChoice == "ножницы":
            print("победил игрок")
    else:
    print('некоректно')
```

Answer (score 1):

Единственная ошибка, которую я вижу, так это то, что у вас "print" написан без отступа
Вот в этом фрагменте

```
elif playerChoice == "камень":
        if botChoice == "бумага":
            print("победил компьютер")
        elif botChoice == "ножницы":
            print("победил игрок")
    else:
    print('некоректно')
```

Правильным будет такой код:

```
import random

loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    print("камень\ножницы\бумага - выпишите или скопируйте и вставьте выбранное вами слово ниже")
    playerChoice = input()

    a = ["бумага", "камень", "ножницы"]

    botChoice = random.choice(a)
    print(botChoice)

    if playerChoice == botChoice:
        print("повторите")
    elif playerChoice == "бумага":
        if botChoice == "камень":
            print("победил игрок")
        elif botChoice == "ножницы":
            print("победил компьютер")
    elif playerChoice == "ножницы":
        if botChoice == "камень":
            print("победил компьютер")
        elif botChoice == "бумага":
            print("победил игрок")
    elif playerChoice == "камень":
        if botChoice == "бумага":
            print("победил компьютер")
        elif botChoice == "ножницы":
            print("победил игрок")
    else:
        print('некоректно')
```

Comment: да, спасибо! видимо когда откатывал всё назад случайно убрал отступ. я исправил, только программа всё равно не работает

Comment: @Unknow404 А какая ошибка выводится? Я попробовал у себя, всё работает.

Comment: я запускаю файл.py с рабочего стола двойным кликом. тут если есть ошибка, то программа просто закрывается

Comment: @Unknow404 для вывода ошибки попробуйте try - except Exception as e: print(str(e)). Можете обернуть весь код (включая import), а можете конкретный участок. Если будет ошибка, то он вам выведет. 
Однако более советую вам использовать IDE PyCharm, очень удобная и подскажет ошибку.

Comment: классная идея, спасибо! но я уже нашёл ошибку. оказывается когда я сохранял программу после изменений она сохранилась отдельным файлом, а файл который я открывал был с ошибками. то есть я исправлял не тот код. спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: @Unknow404 не за что)